# R - upload current ggplot2 to imgur

Tags: r, plot, imgur

The [imguR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imguR/imguR.pdf) package seems to be exactly what I want, but a scan of the docs makes it seem like it only uploads files. Can I upload the current plot device without outputting to a file? Specifically I'm interested in uploading plots created with ggplot2. Here is what I tried:

```
> token = imgur_login()
> ggplot(dstat, aes(x=obs,y=tcp)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
> upload_image(token=token)
Error in file.exists(file) : argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

EDIT: I should add, I'm comfortable with a method that invisibly creates a file in the background then uploads it, this is just for quick showcasing of plots not for perfect presentation

EDIT: Here is the code I have created so far. It does not work well because there seems to be a cache used inside of `account_albums` that is not easily disabled. Any help finalizing this would be appreciated

```
get_or_create_album = function(token) {
  # I can find no way to disable the cache inside
  # account_albums - it always returns the first
  # result unless you login again.
  # So if this function creates the album, then 
  # the user must manually log out and log back in 
  # or this function will happily continue creating the album
  albums = account_albums(ids=F,token=token)
  albums = data.frame(t(sapply(albums,c)))
  album = albums$id[albums$title == "R ggplot2"]
  if (length(album) >= 1)
    return(album[[1]])
  album = create_album(title='R ggplot2',description='Automatic uploads from ggplot2',privacy='public', token=token)
  return(album$id)
}

ggupload = function(token) {
  albumID = get_or_create_album(token)
  x = tempfile(fileext = '.pdf')
  ggsave(filename=x)

  p = last_plot()
  title = ""
  desc = ""
  labels = names(p$labels)
  if ("x" %in% labels && "y" %in% labels)
    title = paste(p$labels$x,"vs",p$labels$y)
    desc = title
  if ("title" %in% labels)
    title = p$labels$title
  imgur_upload(file = x, album = albumID, title=title, description = desc, token = token)
}
```

This works as follows

```
> token = imgur_login()
> ggplot(dstat, aes(x=obs,y=tcp)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
> ggupload(token)
```

Comment: Read the rest of the package documentation and work through the examples. The process you are describing as an acceptable workaround is exactly what the package offers.

Comment: I already read it, and I'm still reading it, but there's a big difference between a working idea and working code. I'm trying to write code that does this, but I can't get anything repeatable - imguR does tons of caching behind the scenes and therefore keeps returning invalid data

Comment: The question suggested you had not set up the loaded package so that calling `imgur` would succeed. There are a lot of missing steps in what you posted.